# How to get a struct FILE from NSURL?

Tags: c, cocoa, posix

I know that I can get a POSIX `int` file handle from NSURL by first using `fh = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingFromURL:url error:NULL]` and then calling `[fh fileDescriptor]`. However, I need to pass a `FILE *` to some C library. How can I convert from the `int` file handle to a proper `FILE` struct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tried this but how about using fdopen() from the standard C library to produce a FILE * from a descriptor?

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Alternatively, I was opting to using '[url path]' and 'fopen()' to open the file. But I thought using 'NSFileHandle' was more Cocoa-like.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found on some Apple developer forum (using NSFileHandle):

```
FILE *my_file_pointer = fdopen([myNsFileHandle fileDescriptor], "r");
```

Ow, Philip also answered it. More about `fdopen()` here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man3/fdopen.3.html